# Axios Youtube Request Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Can anyone see if I'm doing anything wrong here? When I perform the request in the URL I get a response so not sure why I'm getting "undefined"

```
axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos',
    params: {
        part: "snippet",
        id: "rutcaGhQWFI",
        key: youtubeAPIKey
    }
}).then((res) => {
    const results = res.data.results
    console.log("AXIOS", results)
})
```

Comment: Are you sure the response is supposed to have a `results` property? what happens if you log out `res.data`

Comment: Ahhh nice work! Thanks Nicholas